# Is soft resetting bad for the phone?

Tags: soft-reset, nokia-lumia-720

My lumia 720 had a broken screen and it has been replaced, since then phone freezes often, i have to reset it in order to get it back to working state. Does soft resetting have any effects on the phone longevity ? I know soft reset will not harm any of the data or apps stored on the phone. Just wanted to know if it affects the phone itself as such in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A soft reset is equivalent turning the phone (fully) off, and on again, in a asimilar way to removing the battery from phones that had a removable battery. There should be no long term damage from doing this, in the same way there's no risk of damage by switching a traditional PC off by holding the power button for more than 4 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't harm your phone.. Since 720 is a non-removable battery , if it get hangs you have to do soft reset to make your mobile work again no other go..